# how to access custom data-* html5 attribute placed in different tag, commonly in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a in-place editor where I'm fetching the data by putting the custom data attributes in different tags. I want to access the data in jquery selector and update the value accordingly. Please guide me with the common syntax used to fetch data for different tags.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check like this.

```js
 $('*').filter(function() {
   if($(this).data('custom')){
     console.log($(this).data('custom'));
   }
 });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div data-custom="lol">
    1
    </div>
    <p data-custom="wew">
    2
    </p>
    <h1 data-custom="h1">h1</h1>
```

Comment: I've data-custom at lot of places and in different tags like I've in div tag also have in p tag, also have in h1 tag, etc. I'm looking for common selector to fetch data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer it's working but I'm getting a "undefined" terms in my console.log, any luck in overcoming this bug?

Comment: already updated the code, with `condition` so you cant get undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. One last dumb question, how can we select this attribute to have jquery function for example hover function.

Comment: what do you mean, all element with that attribute add hover event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106338/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-nitsonline-and-mmativ).

Comment: Hey can you help me with this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097764/content-editable-cursor-position-to-be-in-editable-div-when-popup-of-text-editor

Answer (score 1):

```
<dic class='test' data-attr='abc' ></div>
$('div.test').attr('data-attr')
```

Comment: thanks a lot i know this selector. But in my web page I've data-* in <p> tag, <h1, h2, h3> tags too, etc. I want to have a common selector.

Comment: Put a class to all the tags and select the tags using class name.

Comment: few of my tags have class too, can I put two class in one tag?

Comment: Try this...its a guess..☺

Comment: Hey Aju it works with $('[data-attr]').. thanks a lot for the help...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have different tags you can add a class to the tags, then select those elements by class name.

```
$('.my-class').each(function(){
    $(this).data('key', myVal);
});
```